# Question on freezing lobster meat

Tags: freezing, lobster

Can cooked lobster meat (which I bought in a fish market the other day) be frozen and, if so, how?  Was thinking just placing it in a Zip-loc bag and placing in the freezer.

This is just a small amount - at $30.00/pound, definitely not going overboard here, but much cheaper than restaurants!

So we're only talking about 1/2 pound but even so, wanted to know if I could freeze it until next week or so.

Thanks-
Randy

Answer (score 2):

Sure, freeze away. It's not going to be as good as eating it fresh but it's better than throwing it away.